# "dependency.assets" is not allowed

Tags: xcode, react-native, podfile

I recently upgrade react-native to 0.69

When I use XCode and I start de project, the project build, but the app don't launch.
I error, I got this :

```js
Package native-base contains invalid configuration: "dependency.assets" is not allowed.
Please verify it's properly linked using "react-native config" command and contact the package maintainers about this.
```

But `react-native config` show nothing, and I don't know how to find a solution.

This is my Podfile :

```js
platform :ios, '12.4'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'

use_react_native! 
target 'myProject' do
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-Core', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/'
  pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/React/CoreModules"
  pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
  pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
  pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
  pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
  pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
  pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
  pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
  pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/RNVectorIcons.podspec'
  pod 'React-cxxreact', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/cxxreact'
  pod 'React-jsi', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi'
  pod 'React-jsiexecutor', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsiexecutor'
  pod 'React-jsinspector', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/jsinspector'
  pod 'React-callinvoker', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/callinvoker"
  pod 'ReactCommon/turbomodule/core', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon"
  pod 'Yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec'
  pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
  pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec"
  pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
  pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
  pod 'react-native-image-picker', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker'
  target 'myProjectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end
  use_native_modules!
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == 'react-native-config'
      phase = target.project.new(Xcodeproj::Project::Object::PBXShellScriptBuildPhase)
      phase.shell_script = "cd ../../"\
      " && RNC_ROOT=./node_modules/react-native-config/"\
      " && export SYMROOT=$RNC_ROOT/ios/ReactNativeConfig"\
      " && ruby $RNC_ROOT/ios/ReactNativeConfig/BuildDotenvConfig.ruby"
      target.build_phases << phase
      target.build_phases.move(phase,0)
    end
  end
end
```

Don't know what to do now

Answer (score -2):

This error happened to me when I ran "react-native run-android".
Root cause of this was Process is already running and port was in use.
I solved this by killing process and running "react-native run-android" again.

```
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-MBPA2485-VP ~ % sudo lsof -i :8081       
COMMAND  PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    1449         root   24u  IPv6 0x1b55fc0361c29747      0t0  TCP *:sunproxyadmin (LISTEN)
node    1449         root   52u  IPv6 0x1b55fc0361c36c47      0t0  TCP [::127.0.0.1]:sunproxyadmin->[::127.0.0.1]:62796 (CLOSED)
node    1449         root   56u  IPv6 0x1b55fc0361c33447      0t0  TCP [::127.0.0.1]:sunproxyadmin->[::127.0.0.1]:62797 (CLOSED)
node    1449         root   58u  IPv6 0x1b55fc0361c33b47      0t0  TCP [::127.0.0.1]:sunproxyadmin->[::127.0.0.1]:62798 (CLOSED)
node    7762 vikaspiprade   25u  IPv4 0x1b55fc11c1f60d8f      0t0  TCP localhost:65228->localhost:sunproxyadmin (ESTABLISHED)
node    9118 vikaspiprade   25u  IPv4 0x1b55fc11c1554d8f      0t0  TCP localhost:49338->localhost:sunproxyadmin (ESTABLISHED)
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-MBPA2485-VP ~ % kill -9 1449
kill: kill 1449 failed: operation not permitted
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-MBPA2485-VP ~ % sudo kill -9 1449
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-MBPA2485-VP ~ % kill -9 1449     
kill: kill 1449 failed: no such process
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-MBPA2485-VP ~ %
```